# How to sum two columns by another column and group by category in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below:

| Category | Item1 | Child of Item1 | Date | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 5 | 6 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

Item1 column has a child that sometimes generate 2 rows with same date, week and category.
How do I use SQL to sum quantity of item1 and child of item1 by week and category but ignore duplicate data in item1 to get data like below:

| Category | Item1 | Child of Item1 | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 7 | 10 | 1 |
| B | 9 | 8 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| B | 4 | 3 | 2 |

Comment: Numbers don't add up, can you please add more info

Comment: I mean if I sum(item1) and sum(child of item1) by week and category, the result for category A, item1 and week 1 will be 10 instead of 7.

Comment: Category `B` week `2` has an inconsistent `item1` total and you say you want to "ignore duplicate data in item1" but there are two `2` values and you give the output as `4` rather than ignoring the duplicate and outputting `2`.

Comment: But they are different date, so they should be added

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    (ColumnA + ColumnB) As Total
From 
   Table_Name
Group By Column_name
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` `category` and `week` and then use `SUM` to aggregate and take only the `DISTINCT` values for `item1`:

```sql
SELECT category,
       SUM(DISTINCT item1) AS item1,
       SUM(child_of_item1) AS child_of_item1,
       week
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY category, week
ORDER BY category, week;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Category, Item1, Child_of_Item1, "Date", Week) AS
SELECT 'A', 3, 2, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, 7, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 4, 1, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 4, 2, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 5, 6, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, 2, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1, 3, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, 2, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, 1, 2, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CATEGORY | ITEM1 | CHILD_OF_ITEM1 | WEEK |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 7 | 10 | 1 |
> | A | 3 | 5 | 2 |
> | B | 9 | 8 | 1 |
> | B | 2 | 3 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b660b7fc360abcd7431c09fe353bf52c)*